# How to make Sub AddSum() run automatically when the excel starts

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a code under Addsum(), which needs to be automatically run when the excel starts.

I have tried several ways like

```
Sub Auto_open
  Sub Addsum()
     ...code
  End Sub
End Sub
```

another method like calling other subs option,

```
Sub RunAll()
  Call Auto_Open
  Call AddSum
End Sub
```

but none seems to satisfy the requirement as running the Addsum() immediately when the workbook opens.

Please guide me!

Comment: Are you trying to run code when the workbook opens? or when excel opens? your question is not clear.

Comment: `Sub Auto_open : AddSum : End Sub`

Comment: Look into [Workbook_Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) Event.

Comment: @braX- i dont want to run any code manually. it should be config in macro in VBA module in such a way that, when i save the code and then later at any time, when i open the doc, the sum should be displayed automatically!

Comment: @TimWilliams Can you please write in () please. How can Subs work without ()

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you TIm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TimWilliams has shown, first place your AddSum procedure in a regular module (Insert >> Module) . . .

```
Sub AddSum()
   ...code
End Sub
```

Then call your procedure from your Auto_open event handler in the code module for ThisWorkbook . . .

```
Sub Auto_open()
  AddSum
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect, yes, I tried in this way

- On Workbook Open code needs to go in ThisWorkbook of the VB Project.

-Double click ThisWorkbook in the VB Editor to view it's code

-Change the drop down at the top from "(General)" to "Workbook"

-Make sure the other drop down at the top is set to "Open"

-Paste in "Call AddSum" within the Workbook_Open event